# Windows blue screen but Linux runs fine

Tags: windows-10, memory, dualboot, memtest86

I have a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Manjaro. I use Linux 99% of the time but it happens that, for some reason, I have to start Windows. Last week, I was welcomed with the famous blue screen. Tried a few more times, only to receive back this blue screen upon login, with a new random error code. From what I could gather, Windows points to faulty memory as the cause. I perform the memory diagnostic with the Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool, but it gets stuck near the end and I have to force restart the computer.

Eventually, I had to achieve some work, so I restart to Linux (which works perfectly BTW). To salve my conscience, I run [memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) on the next day with the default settings. There are so many errors that the test aborts before the end.

[From the doc, I read the following](https://www.memtest86.com/troubleshooting.htm):

> There are some systems that cause MemTest86 to be confused about the size of memory and it will try to test non-existent memory. This will cause a large number of consecutive addresses to be reported as bad and generally there will be many bits in error. If you have a relatively small number of failing addresses and only one or two bits in error you can be certain that the errors are valid. Also intermittent errors are without exception valid.

This leads me to think that it might not be a hardware problem after all. Reason is: memtest normally should report punctal errors, not systematic ones. Additionally, if that many errors were reported, I find it extremely unlikely that Linux would run at all, and as I said: no error, nothing our of the ordinary.

Since I am not an expert at all in hardware or OSes inner workings, I need help to answer these questions:

- How is it possible that Linux runs fine, with no visible problems (including in the system logs) but memtest86 and windows both crash?
- What should I do about it? Should I replace my RAM and hope that it solves the issue? Should I perform a clean install of Windows, assuming that the file system got somehow corrupted?

[UPDATE]: After a few more tries, Windows magically managed to restart without failure. I ran a disk check which threw many errors. I restarted the system in repair mode. After one more failure, I finally got into my session to run a second disk check, without error this time. So I will blame Windows for one more unexplained system failure and hope for the best ! To be continued...

Comment: A possible disk error where Windows is located on the disk?  Get the manufacturer's hardware test app and test al the hardware.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the BSOD?

Comment: @harrymc as I mentioned, the BSOD is not caused by the same error each time I restart the computer, so I doubt that a screenshot will be able to help, but I can provide you one anyway in a few hours if you wish

Comment: @John as far as I know, the manufacturer (Razer) does not provide a hardware test app. However, `fsck` runs successfully each time I boot Linux, which makes me think that it is not a disk error. I will run `fsck` from a USB drive anyway to make sure

Comment: Regular memory will be used by both systems which makes me think disk. It could be video or dedicated video memory.

Comment: Multiple different bsod errors is always a memory issue.

Comment: See the update, if it's really a hardware error, it will soon bite me in the *ss. Thank you all for your advices !

Comment: Smells of driver issue.

Comment: It was one of the memory stick that stopped working